# Remove remaining url after htm?

Tags: c#, url

i need to remove the url path starting from `/deposit/jingdongpay.htm?bid=4089`
'?' i just need `/deposit/jingdongpay.htm`.
It means that the url will remove anything that comes after .htm
Any idea how to do it.

Comment: yes but i just want to remove the path after htm

Comment: `Print left$(url$,20)`

Comment: In PHP: $url = strtok($url, "?");

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use `str.split()`:

```
url = "/deposit/jingdongpay.htm?bid=4089"
split_url = url.split('?')

>>> split_url
['/deposit/jingdongpay.htm', 'bid=4089']
>>> split_url[0]
'/deposit/jingdongpay.htm'
```

Comment: if in c# any idea?

Comment: I think it makes sense to wait until the OP told you which language he codes in

Comment: There is an equivalent `Split` function in C#. See the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.Split` method:

```
string url = "/deposit/jingdongpay.htm?bid=4089";
string result = url.Split('?')[0];
```

Another approach would be to use `String.Substring`:

```
string result = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf('?'));
```

Or maybe if you are interested in a LINQ solution:

```
string result = new string(url.TakeWhile(c => c != '?').ToArray());
```

**result = "/deposit/jingdongpay.htm"**

Comment: As you answered same as mine and faster than me, so deleting my answer, but this doesn't mean I copied your answer.. +1 for your fast response. ;) not hungry of reputation

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar thank you, very correct of you. I believe that you didn't copy my answer, but we had the same methods in the same order so i 
thought that you did.

Comment: I am not who downvoted, reply to your comment `split` is easiest one, if someone says do not use split then normally we use IndexOf and if someone says do not use both of it then we try with TakeWhile.. right? so I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I know that you didn't downvoted, but I am interested why someone else did